# Alternative to nested anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a table where each cell's content is wrapped with an `A` tag set to full height and width, so that the entire cell is clickable.

But some of the cells need to have additional links in their content.

The solution that immediately jumps out is to nest the `A` tags, like so:

```
<td>
   <a href="#" class="cell" >
      Officers include:
      President, Vice president, Secretary, Treasurer,
      <a href="#">7 others</a>
   </a>
</td>
```

But nested `A` tags are illegal.  Is there any workaround that would allow me to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use CSS or JavaScript. I would recommend just using CSS.

### CSS

[This works in my Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsydk/) using CSS only. Basically I just made all child links (except the big one) have `position: relative` and set their `z-index` to higher than the large background link.

#### HTML

```
<div>
    Hello, <a href="http://example.com/hello" class="normal">Bob</a>
    <a href="http://example.com" class="big"></a>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

.big {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;   
  z-index: 0;
}

.normal {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

### JavaScript

Attach a click event to the cell, and an event to all child links. Make sure child links events do not bubble up (`stopPropagation()`).

Comment: I don't think this approach allows keyboard focusing with TAB.

Comment: The CSS solution is very nifty. I'm going to try the JS solution with a TABINDEX attribute on the TD, and maybe that will allow it to be focused.

Comment: @Will If the CSS solution works on all browsers you require to, just use it. I always try to make CSS do what it can without relying on JavaScript :)

Comment: unfortunately, this will make the text inside a div unselectable :(

Comment: Try this JSfiddle example using JavaScript. The CSS version doesn't stop the click from bubbling upwards, which may be OK, but not as clean as the JS IMHO: http://jsfiddle.net/10uwsLkw/1/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like...

```
<td>
   <a href="#" class="cell" >
      Officers include:
      President, Vice president, Secretary, Treasurer,
   </a>
   <a href="#">7 others</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define it like so:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="cell" >
       Officers include:
       President, Vice president, Secretary, Treasurer,
    </a>
    <a href="#">7 others</a>
</td>
```

Surely if the entire cell is clickable that will negate any of the cell's contained links?

Comment: That solves the use case in this Q, but it's not generic, i.e. what if you wanted President to have a different `<a>` tag. To reduce writing duplicate `<a>` tags, it's more elegant to stop DOM events from bubbling up. See this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10uwsLkw/1/