# Stripping off only </a>

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I get a json encoded array through an ajax call..
`var_dump()` of it..

```
0 => array (size=1) 'img' => string '<a href="comment.php?id=1388861073123153033"><div class="gallery-img"><img src="media/uploads/1388861073123153033/1.jpg" data-gallery-target="1388861073123153033" data-gallery-title="first" data-gallery-description="The first image" data-gallery-author="tor" data-gallery-time="1 day ago" /><a class="btn btn-primary gallery-img-pop" href="#" data-gallery-target="1388861073123153033"><span class="fui-photo"></i></a></div></a>' (length=427) 
1 => array (size=1) 'img' => string '<a href="comment.php?id=1388861115385194915"><div class="gallery-img"><img src="media/uploads/1388861115385194915/2.jpg" data-gallery-target="1388861115385194915" data-gallery-title="second" data-gallery-description="The second image" data-gallery-author="tor" data-gallery-time="1 day ago" /><a class="btn btn-primary gallery-img-pop" href="#" data-gallery-target="1388861115385194915"><span class="fui-photo"></i></a></div></a>' (length=429)
```

Then I decode it with jquery and append it to a div:

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
  //alert(response);
  $('#gallery a').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#gallery').html("");
  var decodeCom = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
  setTimeout(function() {
   $.each(decodeCom, function(key,value) {
     $('#gallery').append(value.img).hide().fadeIn(1200);
   });
  }, 500);
});
```

But when I check the html of the `#gallery` div, each of the blocks are missing the last `</a>` tags in it..I even checked `value.img` by adding `alert(value.img)` before `append` it's fine till there but after appending it strips off  the last  `</a>`, why so? What am I doing wrong?

Update:

```
$('.gallery-img').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () { 
    $(this).find('.gallery-img-pop').fadeToggle(100); 
});
```

New response:

```
<a href="comment.php?id=1388861073123153033">
  <div class="gallery-img">
    <img src="media/uploads/1388861073123153033/1.jpg" data-gallery-target="1388861073123153033" data-gallery-title="first" data-gallery-description="The first image" data-gallery-author="tor" data-gallery-time="1 day ago" />
    <span class="btn btn-primary gallery-img-pop" data-gallery-target="1388861073123153033"><i class="fui-photo"></i></span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Update 2 (the whole script) :

```
 ///gallery
  function modalTrigger(targetId) {

    target = $('img[data-gallery-target='+targetId+']');
    id =  $(target).attr('data-gallery-target');
    title = $(target).attr('data-gallery-title');
    src = $(target).attr('src');
    author = $(target).attr('data-gallery-author');
    desc = $(target).attr('data-gallery-description');
    timePosted = $(target).attr('data-gallery-time');

    $('.main-img').html('<img src="'+src+'" />');
    $('.user-link').html(author);
    $('.user-link').attr('href','user.php?id='+author);
    $('#popup-com').attr('href','comment.php?id='+id);
    $('#popup-like').attr('href','comment.php?id='+id);
    $('.user-time').html('- '+timePosted);
    $('.comment-desc').html(desc);
    $("#popup-gallery").modal({ fadeDuration: 1000, fadeDelay: 0.8, zIndex: 210 });

  };

  $('.gallery-img-pop').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var targetId = $(this).attr('data-gallery-target');
    modalTrigger(targetId);
  });

  /* //This is what I had
  $('.gallery-img').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () { 
    alert(1);
    $(this).find('.gallery-img-pop').fadeToggle(100); 
  });
  */

  $('#gallery').on('.gallery-img', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function(){ 
    alert('test');
  });

  $('.main-img').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.modal.close();     
  });

  //search
  //This is what updates #gallery
  function searcher(key) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //abort pending request
    var request;       
    if (request) { 
      request.abort(); 
    } 

    if((key==1) || ($('.pagination').hasClass('isHidden'))) {
      $('.pagination').removeClass('isHidden');
      $('.pagination').fadeIn(1200);
    } else {
      $('.pagination').addClass('isHidden');
      $('.pagination').fadeOut(600);
    } 

    if(key!="") {

      $('#gallery').css({'opacity':'0.4'});
      request = $.ajax({ 
                  url: 'controller/model.php', 
                  type: 'POST',
                  timeout: 2000,
                  cache: false,
                  data: 'key='+key+'&method=searcher',
                });

      request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        //alert(response);
        $('#gallery a').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#gallery').html("");
        var decodeCom = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.each(decodeCom, function(key,value) {
            //alert(value.img);
            $('#gallery').append(value.img).hide().fadeIn(1200);
          });
        }, 500);
      });

      request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        alert('Failed, please reload');
      });

      request.always(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert($("#gallery").html());
          $('#gallery').css({'opacity':'1'});
        }, 3000);
      });

    } else {

      alert("Can't be empty");

    }

  };
```

Comment: You're not supposed to nest anchor(`a`) tags. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: @tewathia yes,  I replaced them by `span`, now it's also removing the closing slash for img tag, why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your update issue with 'on' hover.  You are setting up the listeners before they have been added to the dom.
Change your [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to:

```
$('#gallery').on(
   'mouseenter mouseleave', 
   '.gallery-img',   
   function(){ 
         alert('test')
    }
 )
```

Other important things I see in your code.  Your function 
`function modalTrigger(targetId) {` declares a bunch of variables on the global scope.  You should prefix them with var.

e.g.:

```
 var target = $('img[data-gallery-target='+targetId+']')
```

Your click functions reference an event variable that you never include.

---

Original issue:

Two major issues with your markup (probably related), and a nest of an anchor.

```
<a href="comment.php?id=1388861073123153033">
```

Will get closed immediately.

Other issues

1. Random close tag of a `</i>`
2. Unclosed `<span class="fui-photo">` tag..
3. Space inside of the data-gallery-title attribute `data-gall ery-title="first"`

I think you need to change

```
<span class="fui-photo"></i>
```

to

```
<span class="fui-photo"></span>
```

---

Here is the markup you are returning:

```
<a href="comment.php?id=1388861073123153033">
    <div class="gallery-img">
        <img src="media/uploads/1388861073123153033/1.jpg" data-gallery-target="1388861073123153033" data-gallery-title="first" data-gallery-description="The first image" data-gallery-author="tor" data-gallery-time="1 day ago" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary gallery-img-pop" href="#" data-gallery-target="13 88861073123153033"><span class="fui-photo"></i></a>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="comment.php?id=1388861115385194915">
    <div class="gallery-img">
        <img src="media/uploads/1388861115385194915/2.jpg" data-gallery-target="1388861115385194915" data-gallery-title="second" data-gallery-description="The second image" data-gallery-author="tor" data-gallery-time="1 day ago" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary gallery-img-pop" href="#" data-gallery-target=" 1388861115385194915">
            <span class="fui-photo"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: The space was because of next line in var_dump..i'll fix the other two and check..

Comment: Ok, I changed the markup as you suggested, also changed the inner anchor to `span`, but the  is issue, on page load, I load the images directly through php, but then when I update it with jquery, the span tag does not appear on hover where as if done by php it appears, and also the html comes out properly(i.e not stripping of anchor tag)..see the update which triggers the span on hover..

Comment: Update your post above to your new response.

Comment: Span is still not closed.

Comment: When do you setup your `$('.gallery-img').on`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44573/discussion-between-nix-and-blo)