# Slim nested linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

How i can implement nested linking logic in slim?
I need some html:

```
<a href='first_url'>
  <div class='some_class'>
    <a href='second_url'>
      ...
    </a>
  </div>
</a>
```

my code

```
= link_to 'first_url' do
  .some_class
    = link_to 'second_url' do
      ...
```

but i see wrong html:

```
<a href='first_url'></a>
<div class='some_class'>
  <a href='first_url'></a>
  <a href='second_url'></a>
</div>
```

how i can fix this error? any ideas?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal - nested a tags are not valid html - so perhaps the browser is correcting the generated html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Ian Kenny` pointed out in his comment ***nested anchor tags is not valid HTML so instead of nesting anchor tags you can use some js magic on container element to achieve same thing:***

```
.some_class#first-url
  = link_to second_anchor_path do
    Second Anchor
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on("click","#first-url",function(){
  window.location.href = '/some_url';
});
```