# Block-level self-closing anchor tag not working as it should

Tags: css, html, wordpress, hyperlink

Weird HTML behaviour happening here. I have an `<a href>` link wrapped around a whole  tag, itself containing the article details. The objective is to make the whole Article Block clickable.

However, once I run the code in the browser, the ahref self closes itself, and many occurrences appear around each child element within the ARTICLE block. The bad news is that it does not make the whole article block clickable.

```
article { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }

.page-header, .entry-header { padding: 0; }

.entry-title, .page-title { margin-top: 0; line-height: 1; padding: 1em .8em 0 .8em; }

.entry-header { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;  }

.entry-thumb { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(70,64,60,1); }
.entry-thumb img { width: 100%; }

.opacity { opacity: .6; }
.opacity:hover { opacity: 1; }

.header-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(70,64,60,1) 5%, rgba(70,64,60, 0) 50%);
}
.header-overlay.male { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,155,.5) 5%, rgba(0,0,155, 0) 50%); }
.header-overlay.female { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,255,.5) 5%, rgba(255,0,255, 0) 50%); }

.header-overlay h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.header-overlay .entry-meta a { color: #FFF; }
.header-overlay .entry-meta { 
    line-height: 2;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: .7;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

And the source AS I CODED IT:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <figure class="entry-thumb">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array('class' => 'opacity') ); } ?>
            </figure>
            <div class="header-overlay">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="entry-meta"><?php wordpress_posted_on(); ?></div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
</a>
```

Weird thing is that it outputs THAT code with several ahref...

```
    <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark"></a>

<article id="post-26" class="post-26 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorised">
    <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark">
    </a>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark">
            <figure class="entry-thumb">
                <img width="640" height="480" src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" class="opacity wp-post-image" alt="Blue_merle_picture"> </figure>
        </a>
        <div class="header-overlay">
            <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark">
                <h1>
                    Blue Merle Dog              </h1>
            </a>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark">
                    <span class="posted-on">Posted on </span></a>
                <a href="http://localhost/Wordpress/uncategorised/blue-merle/" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2015-04-24T00:26:55+00:00">24th April 2015</time>
                </a><span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://localhost/Wordpress/author/administrator/">Admin</a></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</article>
```

I wouldn't mind but it is not making the whole block clickable, only the h1 title and the post metas (date and author)..

**EDIT:** my php/wordpress loop is basic as here below.

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With that line: *get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );* calling for the code above (the article block.)

Comment: This looks like what an IE8 would render – in modern borwsers this should work as expected. But be aware, that a block level link must be set to `display: block;` to properly work across browsers. Please also refer to http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/ and https://www.seroundtable.com/block-level-links-google-seo-16369.html

Comment: @feeela I am using Chrome and I am surprised as it should work. Perhaps it has to do with my child elements using position:absolute and relative? Hmm, getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
```

To this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="entry-link">
```

Then add this CSS:

```
.entry-link {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.entry-link:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.entry-link:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Just noticed your output...can you show us the PHP loop you're using?

**UPDATE 2:** Removed float and add clearfix method for your anchor. But, judging from your output you still get some weird anchors everywhere, could you show us your PHP loop?

Comment: Just tried with the float left, it does make the entire block clickable however it messes up with the layout and all the title are stacked up on top of the first block only.

Comment: tried again with the new css but still the same. I updated my question with all the PHP loop - I don't get where these ahrefs come from when I am clearly using one and only one!

Comment: @Lazhar Don't suppose you remember if you ever solved this? I'm getting exactly the same thing. Extremely confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I figured out what the problem is thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal).

Imagine you have the following

```
<a href="link.html">
  <p> <a href="link2.html">Foo</a> </p>
</a>
```

Which url are you going to go to when you click on the internal anchor?

I'm not *exactly* what function/mechanism autocloses tags if it detects a nested anchor tag but that is essentially what cause and therefor effect is.

Bottom line is: don't nest anchor tags in WordPress, it's illegal HTML so it prevents it.