# Get href values from all <a> tags, including nested <a> tags

Tags: php, html, regex, href, domdocument

I've been searching for hours (there shouldn't be any duplicate) and attempting many different ways, using both RegEx (regular expressions) and DOMdocument, without success.

**Non-Standard HTML Code:**

```
<a class="SOMECLASS" href="javascript:__FUNCTION(SOME_HREF_INSIDE)" onclick="SOME_JS_FUNCTION();" id="SOME_ID" style="SOME_STYLE">
    <a href="SOME_URL_3">SOME TEXT</a>
</a>
```

Now the problem is I'm trying to get the url "SOME_URL_3" and both when parsing using RegEx or DOMdocument, the pasing stops as soon as it encounters the first href. Of course as the second "a" tag is part of the first one, the parser only sees it as one.

I observed that browsers seem to automatically separate the tags when parsing as follow.

**Before:**

```
<a href="SOME_URL">
    <a href="SOME_URL_2">
    </a>
</a>
```

**After:**

```
<a href="SOME_URL">
</a>
<a href="SOME_URL_2">
</a>
```

I've not been able to replicate this browsers behavior using php.

**Previous Attempt:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
    $href_count = 0;
    $attrs = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $link->attributes->length; ++$i) {
        $node = $link->attributes->item($i);
        if ($node->nodeName == "href") {
            $attrs[$node->nodeName][$href_count] = $node->nodeValue;
            $href_count++;
            if ($href_count >= 2) {
                echo "A second href has been found";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($attrs);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

As you may expect, it unfortunately doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't be here asking for help...

Please do not hesitate to share your knowledge, any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

---

## **Update:**

I had forgotten to specify in my initial question that the answer should still allow to capture href from standard/non-nested "a" tags. My goal is to extend/improve my existing HTML parser to ensure that I'm also retrieving the urls from any href attribute. My initial code was only using RegEx and I wasn't able to capture a additional href from within a nested "a" tags. The solution I'm looking for would allow to capture href both from nested and standard/non-nested "a" tags. Brandon White's solution is great for nested href only. However, it would be resource consuming to use two different RegEx (nested/non-nested) to parse the entire HTML content twice. An ideal solution would be a RegEx allowing to capture both at the same time, if this is possible.

Comment: Why would you ever want nested anchor tags?

Comment: I unfortunately have no control at all over the content I'm reading and I can ensure you that this is not part of my practice.

Thank you for asking.

Comment: Could you not technically use a REGEX lookaround to capture the two anchor tags? Further extracting the two and removing all but the final `href` value?

Comment: I actually tried something very similar using something like: if (substr_count($html, "href") > 1) { use a regex here to get the url } but my problem using this method is that I'm not sure how to grab the $link variable raw html from my foreach loop. (Please see code in my question) If I could get a hand on it, your idea would possibly work.

Comment: Relevant reading about invalid HTML: [Why are nested anchor tags illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666915/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution extracts all `<a>` tag `href` values, whether nested or not.

### UPDATE 2024-03-16:

As highlighted by @mickmackusa, it appears that DOMDocument now automatically parses nested `<a>` tags as sibling tags, which makes the previous solution irrelevant.

It is now possible to extract all nested and standard/non-nested `<a>` tags, simply by iterating over the result of the getElementsByTagName('a') function, as shown below.

**Updated Solution:** [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z9mUW)

```
$result = <<<HTML
<a href="SOME_URL">
    <a href="SOME_URL_2">
        <a href="SOME_URL_DEEP">
        </a>
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL3">
    <a href="SOME_URL_4">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL_5">
</a>
<a href="SOME_URL_6">
</a>

HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $output[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => SOME_URL
    [1] => SOME_URL_2
    [2] => SOME_URL_DEEP
    [3] => SOME_URL3
    [4] => SOME_URL_4
    [5] => SOME_URL_5
    [6] => SOME_URL_6
)
</pre>
```

For those looking to discard any href from the `<a>` tags containing nested `<a>` tags, you may refer to @mickmackusa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77785595/4089580) below.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

While the original goal was to retrieve all `<a>` tags, whether nested or not, the solution below ignored any href from the `<a>` tags containing nested `<a>` tags. I actually ended up using a slightly different version, which was retrieving all `<a>` tags.

However, since DOMDocument now automatically parses nested `<a>` tags as sibling tags, the condition present in the foreach loop is never met and the result always contains all `<a>` tags.

**Original Solution:** [Demo](https://3v4l.org/NjYF2)

```
$result = <<<HTML
<a href="SOME_URL">
    <a href="SOME_URL_2">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL3">
    <a href="SOME_URL_4">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL_5">
</a>
<a href="SOME_URL_6">
</a>

HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $tag_html = $dom->saveHTML($link); // Get tag inner html
    
    if (substr_count($tag_html, "href") > 1) { // If tag contains more than one href attribute
        preg_match_all('/href="([^"]*)"/is', $tag_html, $link_output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $output[] = $link_output[1][1]; // Output second href
    } else { //Not nested tag
        $output[] = $link->getAttribute('href'); // Output first href
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Original Output:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => SOME_URL_2
    [1] => SOME_URL_4
    [2] => SOME_URL_5
    [3] => SOME_URL_6
)
</pre>
```

**Updated Output:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => SOME_URL
    [1] => SOME_URL_2
    [2] => SOME_URL3
    [3] => SOME_URL_4
    [4] => SOME_URL_5
    [5] => SOME_URL_6
)
</pre>
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless if there is not dot (any character) in the pattern.

Comment: This answer does not work as required.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/NjYF2

Comment: @mickmackusa, when testing again today, all <a> tags are now present in the result, even when removing the condition within the foreach loop. Demo: https://3v4l.org/M2eXU. Strangely, testing with different php versions down to 5.0 does not affect the result. However, at the time, nested <a> tags were not listed within the DOMdocument object, which is why I had to rely on an alternative solution. It seems that DOMDocument's behavior has somehow changed in the meantime, which explains the discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do what you're asking with some pretty fancy RegEx. Using *Negative Lookahead* and some logic, you can actually extract the nested href location altogether.

### Example

```
$result = <<<HTML
<a href="SOME_URL">
    <a href="SOME_URL_2">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL3">
    <a href="SOME_URL_4">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL5">
</a>
<a href="SOME_URL_6">
</a>

HTML;

preg_match_all('/<a.*>(?!<\/a>)\s*<a.*href\s*=\s*"(.+)"/', $result, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

### Explanation

RegEx is VERY handy in these tricky situations. There is no need, thankfully, for all of the logic you were attempting above. All you need is some logic and knowledge of RegEx. A site I always recommend is [RegExr](http://regexr.com). It is very helpful to analyze and build working RegEx. In fact, here is a [RegEx "Fiddle"](http://www.regexr.com/3c0t5) of the example.

- `<a.*>` This matches any first anchor tag
- `(?!<\/a>)` This is a *negative lookahead* - which checks to make sure there is **NOT** a closing anchor tag following. This assures it is a nested anchor match.
- `\s*` Matches any possible white-space between the two anchors.
- `<a.*href\s*=\s*"(.+)"` This matches the second anchor tag written with any possible spaces between the href attribute and `=` and value. Also, the `(.+)` places the URL into a *capturing group*. Using the [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function, it will be the second row in the `$match` array. See the example output below.
- Also notice, it doesn't extract the non-nested URLs like shown in your code example above.

### Output of Code

[image: Output of Code example above]

Comment: Hi Brandon, I have just posted a solution as by the meantime I was working on it. As you can see I didn't accept any answer yet. I didn't test yours but it seems that you are more experienced with RegEx than I am. I see that your solution is lighter than mine although less customizable. Do you think your solution would work with both nested and regular "a" tags while parsing complete html pages?

Comment: It would absolutely work with non nested, although you would need to alter it, in one of two ways. Rewrite a different RegEx equation for standard anchor tags and running it separately, or encapsulate both types in a group. This is of course, assuming you would like to keep them separate. You can use exactly what I have given you above to attempt what you are doing. I would like to stress how useful RegEx can be, and advise you to take this opportunity to learn.

Comment: Hi Brandon, would it be possible with only one modified version of your RegEx to retrieve all href inside of the "a" tags either there would be one or then of them? If this is possible, I would simply have to apply a certain logic afterward to select which one to keep or simply all. This would be the perfect solution. Please let me know, you are the RegEx artist.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use only a single Regular Expression to do this. Although, your original question was for nested anchors. Again, if I were you, I would use this as a learning experience to create what you're trying to do. Check out [RegExr](http://regexr.com), especially looking at the "Reference" tab on the left. All of the necessary information is explained above. **Hint:** You will want to look at _non-capturing groups_ as well, so as to not mess up your array.

Comment: Hi again Brandon, unfortunately I'm on a project and I don't have enough time to improve that part of the script for now. I know that using RegEx only would probably make the code more efficient and less consuming but for now this is not my number one priority. I would still like to thank you very much for your efforts and collaboration on this one, this is very appreciated! If I have enough free time I should come back one day to improve my answer and hopefully come up with a one-liner. Thanks again and have a nice one!

Comment: @BrandonWhite this answer does not fulfill the brief.

Answer (score 0):

Feeding the nested `<a>` tags (invalid HTML) to DOMDocument will cause the structure to be automatically parsed as sibling `<a>` tags (no longer parent-child). This behavior makes originally nested tags indistinguishable from originally sibling tags.

As a desperate attempt to purge the parent tags BEFORE feeding the text to the DOM parser, I have written a regex which will successively remove parent `<a>` tags until there are none left. Then a DOM parser can do what it is good at.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/p16eeM))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="SOME_URL">
    <a href="SOME_URL_2">
        <a href="SOME_URL_DEEP">
        </a>
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL3">
    <a href="SOME_URL_4">
    </a>
</a>

<a href="SOME_URL_5">
</a>
<a href="SOME_URL_6">
</a>

HTML;

do {
    $html = preg_replace(
        '#<a[^>]*>(?:(?!</?a).)*(<a[^>]*>(?:(?!</?a).)*</a>)(?:(?!</?a).)*</a>#si',
        '$1',
        $html,
        -1,
        $count
    );
} while ($count);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $result[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'SOME_URL_DEEP',
  1 => 'SOME_URL_4',
  2 => 'SOME_URL_5',
  3 => 'SOME_URL_6',
)
```

Make no mistake, when using regex to try to parse HTML (valid/invalid), there will be exceptions and anomalies.

---

After the question was clarified to extract all hrefs from all `<a>` tags, no regex is needed.

Pure DOMDocument: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UpLi3))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $result[] = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
var_export($result);
```

DOMDocument + XPath: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mjRJR))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$result = [];
foreach ((new DOMXPath($dom))->evaluate("//a/@href") as $node) {
    $result[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: this behavior where nested <a> tags are automatically parsed as sibling tags appears to have been introduced since I posted my question. The fact that nested <a> tags were missing from the DOMDocument was the main reason why I had to rely on an alternative solution to also extract these href values. DOMDocument did not behave like modern browsers at the time when facing nested <a> tags. If DOMDocument now shares the same behavior as modern browsers and accounts for all <a> by default, my question might not be relevant anymore on recent php versions.

Comment: After your update, there is no need for regex.