# Descendant selector help CSS

Tags: css

Very new to HTML and CSS but trying to learn a new skill.

I am trying to select the "Read More" anchor tag nested inside an anchor and an li tag.I cannot seem to work out the descendant selector that will select this tag in CSS. Any help would be appreciated. I would like to do this without adding any additional classes or ID's.

The code is below.

```
`<ul>
  <li class="Directory">
   <a href="#">
    <img class="icon" src="images/folder.png">
    <h4>Directory</h4>
    <h5>Map View, Locations,<br>Companies,Vendors</h5>
    <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
    <p>Pellentesque ac dui elit. Ut sollicitudin faucibus tellus ut rutrum.   Nam pretium fringilla dignissim.</p>
    <a href="#" >Read More</a>
   </a>`
```

Comment: You should not nest `<a>` in `<a>`.

Comment: There are all sorts of ways you could select this element, but as said, you first need to sort out the invalid HTML, as you can't have an `a` within an `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Danny pointed out, you can use a:last-child to target it. I agree with makshh that you shouldn't nest an a inside an a. One thing I would suggest is reducing the specificity of the target though. Here's a good read on why it's important to do so and an updated example:

[Strategies for keeping CSS specificity low](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/)

```css
.Directory a:last-child {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="Directory">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon" src="images/folder.png">
      <h4>Directory</h4>
      <h5>Map View, Locations,<br>Companies,Vendors</h5>
      <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
      <p>Pellentesque ac dui elit. Ut sollicitudin faucibus tellus ut rutrum. Nam pretium fringilla dignissim.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not only should you not nest anchor tags, you are not allowed to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use: **`:last-child`**

Something like this:

```css
ul li.Directory a:last-child {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="Directory">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon" src="images/folder.png">
      <h4>Directory</h4>
      <h5>Map View, Locations,<br>Companies,Vendors</h5>
      <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
      <p>Pellentesque ac dui elit. Ut sollicitudin faucibus tellus ut rutrum. Nam pretium fringilla dignissim.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you need to change the link appearance you can add **`:link`**. Something like this:

```css
ul li.Directory a:last-child:link {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="Directory">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="icon" src="images/folder.png">
      <h4>Directory</h4>
      <h5>Map View, Locations,<br>Companies,Vendors</h5>
      <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
      <p>Pellentesque ac dui elit. Ut sollicitudin faucibus tellus ut rutrum. Nam pretium fringilla dignissim.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Btw, it's a good practice validate your markup. I'd like to recommend you the next links:

- [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)
- [CSS Validation Service](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options)

This is very important because it helps us to follow the W3C standards significantly, and avoid compatibility problems between browsers.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.....The last child selector worked. I have read a little more on the link nested within a link and will reconsider the code.

Comment: Yes, try to work with these validators links to avoid mistakes in the markup. This will help alot.