# How to open link url inside fancybox content?

Tags: javascript, html, url, fancybox, modal-window

Im using fancybox 2.1.5 and my html and js looks like this:

```
<a href="new-window" class="wrap">
   any content
   <a href="google.com" target="_blank">go google it</a>
</a>


$('.wrap').fancybox();
```

And the question is how to open **only** google link by click on it instead of whole fancybox modal window. now it opens url and modal, which is not right. click out of google link should open as fancybox.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/18666915/1055987

Answer (score 0):

On my experience from the last project, i used php check this example:

```
<?php 

echo '<td><div align="center"><a rel="facebox" href="vieworders.php?id='.$row['confirmation'].'" title="Click To View Orders" style="color:#FCFEFF">View Orders</a>';

?>
```