# How to move specific text upwards within same div?

Tags: html, css

I have 1 div with two separate sections of text. However, one of these sections of text is smaller than the other, leaving it slightly lower than the other section.

I would like it to be centered both vertically and horizontally within the div - inline with the larger text... margin-bottom is not working, however margin-left and margin-right are... how do I do this? Thankyou.

```css
.portfolioHeader {
  position: relative;
  font-family: coolfont;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-align: left;
}
a.miniheader {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
span.smallerish {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioHeader"><a class="header" href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/portfolio">Portfolio ><a class = "miniheader" href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/portfolio/website-design"><span class = "smallerish">di Matteos</span></a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to happen? The bigger text is on top and the smaller one is at the bottom?

Comment: I want the smaller text to be in line with the larger text

Comment: nested `a` tags? invalid html

Comment: then don't use another a tag for the second text. Use span inside the a tag.

Comment: but i want the second text to have a different link

Comment: Don't use nested anchor tags in your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal - if you want two seperate links, make them siblings.

Comment: `<a>url <a>another</a> </a>` is invalid. Use `<a>url</a> <a>another</a>`instead. --- `margin-bottom` does work if you set them to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Fix invalid html
2. Put the font sizes on the anchors
3. Vertical align the anchors
4. If you want the text horizontally centered, then use text-align center on the div (instead of left with margin)

```css
.portfolioHeader {
  position: relative;
  font-family: coolfont;
  top: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

a.header {
  font-size: 55px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

a.miniheader {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
span.smallerish {
  color: #3F3F3F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioHeader">
  <a class="header" href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/portfolio">Portfolio &gt;</a>
  <a class="miniheader" href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/portfolio/website-design"><span class = "smallerish">di Matteos</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thankyou very much.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help - I just edited the answer because I saw you wanted it horizontally centered as well

Answer (score 0):

Set vertical property of anchor tag

```
.portfolioHeader a
{
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to vertical-align the 'a' tags.
This css should help.

```
.portfolioHeader {
   color: black;
   display: table;
   font-family: coolfont;
   font-size: 55px;
   margin-left: 70px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: left;
   top: 20px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }

  a {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }

  a.miniheader {
      left: 30px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      top: -5px;
  }
  span.smallerish {
      color: #3f3f3f;
      font-size: 35px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
```