# Unable to wrap div with anchor tags in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have a view with a div.  The div has a bunch of content including links.  I want to make the entire div clickable.

In my view.html.erb file it looks something like this:

```
<a href="/google">
  <div class="container">
    content with other anchor tags
  </div>
</a>
```

But it renders like this:

```
<a href="/google"></a>
<div class="container">
  <a href="/google"></a>
  content with other anchor tags
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a block for your code:

```
<%= link_to "/google" do %>
  <div class="container">
    content
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That code will render the following html

```
<a href="/google">
  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I get the same result with this.  I think my browser, chrome, gets messed up when I have nested anchor tags.  Maybe this is illegal

Comment: You might be correct that nested anchor tags are illegal.

I found [this link on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal) when searching for nested anchor tags

In any event, my result will render the proper html that you are looking for, but you may need to modify what it is you want the content to be.  If you can figure out what change you want to make, I might be able to help you with the new modification as well.

Comment: I think I will just have to use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3494108/4584963 to be able to effectively nest links.  I will mark your answer correct because it seems like nesting anchor tags is illegal.