# Why adding an <a> breaks the whole HTML structure?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code:

```
$data['full'] .= "<li>".
                    "<a href='/myweb/qanda/".$end["id"]."/".$end["subject"]."'>".
                        '<div class="tools">
                            <div class="numb">'.$end["total_votes"].
                                '<div class="vote_text">رای</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="numb_viewed">'.$end["total_viewed"].
                                '<div class="viewed_text">بازدید</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>'.
                        '<div class="context">'.
                            '<div class="sub_title">'.$end["cat"]."</div>
                            <h2 class='$paidQuestionSubjectCls'>".$end["subject"].'</h2>'.
                            "<h4>".strip_tags($end["body_html"])."</h4>".
                        '</div>'.
                    "</a>".
                "</li>";
```

Which will be generated like this:

[image: demo]

All fine. Everything is wrapped into `a` tag.

---

Now I need to add this line into code above:

```
<a class="tag" href="somethin">برچسب1</a>
```

Here is the resulting code:

```
$data['full'] .= "<li>".
                    "<a href='/myweb/qanda/".$end["id"]."/".$end["subject"]."'>".
                        '<div class="tools">
                            <div class="numb">'.$end["total_votes"].
                                '<div class="vote_text">رای</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="numb_viewed">'.$end["total_viewed"].
                                '<div class="viewed_text">بازدید</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>'.
                        '<div class="context">'.
                            '<div class="sub_title">'.$end["cat"]."</div>
                            <h2 class='$paidQuestionSubjectCls'>".$end["subject"].'</h2>'.
                            "<h4>".strip_tags($end["body_html"])."</h4>".
                            '<a class="tag" href="somethin">برچسب1</a>'. // this is added
                        '</div>'.
                    "</a>".
                "</li>";
```

But surprisingly it will be generated incorrectly:

[image: demo]

See? `div.context` element has jumped out of the `a` tag. How can I keep everything inside `a`?

Comment: `<a>` tag inside `<a>` tag __is invalid markup__

Comment: `<a>` inside `<a>` is invalid

Comment: Also check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: <a> tag inside <a> tag

Answer (score 3):

Because you have an anchor in your anchor:

```
<a href="#first">first <a href="#second">second</a></a>
 ^------------- that one closes here ------------^   ^
                        ^-------- this closes here --^
```

It's not like a div in a div for anchors / inline elements. It's worth noting that if you encounter a problem similar to this, it's this kind of problem in 95% of the cases.

Comment: Nested anchors are indeed prohibited by the HTML specification, so the nested anchor syntax is simply invalid HTML.