# Can we add more than one src URL to same image in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I wanted to add multiple src URL's for a single image using HTML. Is that even possible?

Comment: what do you expect to happen on click?

Comment: So one click opens multiple tabs (all pointing to separate links)? Doesn't sound like good intuitive behavior end users would thank you for, and I wouldn't recommend nesting anchor links (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal)

Comment: are u looking to have many clickable areas on the image where each will be sent to a different location?

Comment: If the browser fails to load the image from the first url, then it should switch to the next one. I want this to happen. Just how it works with font families, we can declare different font families in a row and if one fails to operate browser just switches to the following suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with html alone, but you can use the *[global event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)* `onerror` as an attribute in the following manner demonstrated in the linked JSFiddle and embedded code snippet below.

*Note:* concerning the demonstrations below, alter the filepaths to the specified images sources to observe the adjusted behaviour.

[JSFiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/aky7tq2L/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-1" 
     onError="this.onerror=null; /* to prevent infinite loops */
     
              this.src='https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-2'; /* default */
              
              /* first condition */
              if (this.src != 'https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-2') {
                  this.src='https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-3';
                  
                  /* second condition */
                  if (this.src != 'https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-3') {
                      this.src='https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-4';
                      
                      /* third condition */
                       if (this.src != 'https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-4') {
                           this.src='https://placehold.it/500x500?text=img-5'
                       }
                  }
              } 
">
```

More on [GlobalEventHandlers.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: Thank you sir. It worked for me. Stuck on this around a week now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad I could share this solution and that you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With Css I dont think so, 
But with Javascript ? 
Yeah possible if you want user to get it open multiple links when clicked in that image,

```
//jquery
$('img').click(function(e) {
   window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
   window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try picture tag

```
    <picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```