# Strange closing of <a> tag

Tags: php, html

```
        <a href="<?php echo $url_werkwijze['url']; ?>" modal="modal_werkwijze_1" id="werkwijze_1" class="one-half first proces">
        <div class="title">
            <?php echo 'het proces'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="proceslijn">
            <img class="line" src="<?php echo $background_iconen['url']; ?>"/>
            <?php
            if( have_rows('icons') ){
                $k = 1;
                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('icons') ) {
                the_row();
                $icon_afbeelding = get_sub_field('icon');   
                $icon_title = get_sub_field('title');
                $url_icon = get_sub_field('url_icon');  
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $url_icon['url']; ?>" class="icons" id="icon_<?php echo $k++; ?>">

                    <img src="<?php echo $icon_afbeelding['url']; ?>"/>

                    <span><?php echo $icon_title; ?></span>
                </a>    

                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
         </div>

    </a>
```

But somehow it generates this code in de browser:

```
<a href="https://somewebsite.nl/werkwijze-stappen/#het-proces" modal="modal_werkwijze_1" id="werkwijze_1" class="one-half first proces" style="width: 50%;">
        <div class="title" style="top: 30vh;">
            het proces          </div>
        </a>
<div class="proceslijn"><a href="https://somewebsite.nl/werkwijze-stappen/#het-proces" modal="modal_werkwijze_1" id="werkwijze_1" class="one-half first proces" style="width: 50%;">
            <img class="line" src="https://somewebsite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/lijn_proces.png">
                                </a><a href="https://somewebsite.nl/werkwijze-stappen/#luisteren" class="icons" id="icon_1">

                    <img src="https://somewebsite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/luisteren.png">

                    <span>...Luisteren</span>
                </a>    

                                    <a href="https://somewebsite.nl/werkwijze-stappen/#denken" class="icons" id="icon_2">

                    <img src="https://somewebsite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/denken.png">

                    <span>...Denken</span>
                </a>    

                                    <a href="https://somewebsite.nl/werkwijze-stappen/#doen" class="icons" id="icon_3">

                    <img src="https://somewebsite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/doen.png">

                    <span>...Doen</span>
                </a>    

        </div>
```

The strange thing is that it's generating an a tag after the div class="title".

It's getting even stranger because when i replace the parent a tag in to a div. The generated code is as expected. Anyone any solutions?

Comment: I suspect the HTML you are generating is invalid, and the browser is showing you its corrected interpretation. If I'm reading this right, your code would end up nesting a link inside another link.

Comment: Is this the source as it si send to the browser, or is this the result you see in the DOM when you instepct the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange behaviour occurs because you have nested anchors in your code, which is not allowed (you can find explanation [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal))

Restructure your html code differently to avoid nested anchors.

Comment: The first part is correct, but the second statement is wrong. An `a` element must not have any [`interactive content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content) as descendant, which is any element the user can interact with like `button`, `input`, `a`, `audio`, `label`, ...   (This is also mentioned in one of the answers of the question you linked)

Comment: oh yes, my bad - corrected

Comment: Thnx! I still needed the nested links so I solved it with jquery  now.