# How do I wrap an a tag around a div tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm modifying a WordPress theme and I have this piece of code:

```
// Product link
$product_link_atts = ' href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"';

<a<?php echo $product_link_atts; ?>><!-- Begin my a tag -->
    <div class="nm-shop-loop-details">
        <?php if ( $nm_globals['wishlist_enabled'] ) : ?>
        <div class="nm-shop-loop-wishlist-button"><?php nm_wishlist_button(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h3><a<?php echo $product_link_atts; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php 
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

        <div class="nm-shop-loop-after-title <?php echo esc_attr( $nm_theme_options['product_action_link'] ); ?>">
            <div class="nm-shop-loop-price">
                <?php
                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="nm-shop-loop-actions">
                <?php
                    if ( $quickview_enabled ) {
                        echo apply_filters( 'nm_product_quickview_link', '<a' . $quickview_link_atts . '>' . esc_html__( 'Show more', 'nm-framework' ) . '</a>' );
                    }

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a><!-- Close my a tag -->
```

I'm trying to wrap an a tag around this piece of code (starts line 4).

```
<a<?php echo $product_link_atts; ?>><!-- Begin my a tag -->
```

But somehow the a tag is broken when it's compiled.

This is how it looks like when inspected via Chrome:
[image: the issue]

As you can see the a element is being closed before it wraps itself around the div. I've done some research and I read that since HTML5 it's possible to wrap a elements around div elements.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing here, am I just missing something stupid, or am I actually trying to do something that doesn't work.

Comment: What is in $product_link_atts? Maybe there is a ">" or somethings simelar

Comment: I tried it also once, since there is no apparent error it's somehow puzzling why it won't work, summing that with the fact that the element has just one letter, it's also somehow complex to find exactly why it cannot work.

Comment: @Hackbard I've updated my code to show the $product_link_atts variable, it's on line 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML forbids nesting anchor tags inside other anchor tags.

This is why you won't be able to do it and this is why it closes itself before it happens.

[Why are nested anchor tags illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try to figure out a fix!

Comment: When I did my mistake on this I just created a button object containing the other ones and set the area of it clickable to a link.

Comment: Yea, what I normally do is just display: block the element and then everything renders clickable. But because this is a woocommerce template alot of stuff is getting called via hooks, so I have no control over all the nested elements. Not really sure yet how I'm going to solve this one :D

Answer (score 1):

We need to see the output of some of the php values there to get a better idea of what html really looks like. If you could take a screenshot of the sourcecode (ctrl+U) it would be more helpful than what was interpreted by chrome.

However, I've noticed you have an anchor element inside another one.

Avoid doing this.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Well, there isn't much to avoid if HTML forbids it. You might as well try. HTML will ignore it anyway. :/