# Weird nested a tags issue in Laravel

Tags: html, anchor

When I put an a tag inside another a tag (nested a tags) in any page of my Laravel site, each tag get separated in output html!
for example I wrote this markup:

```
<a href="#">Test 1
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
</a>
```

output html :

```
<a href="#">Test 1</a>
<a href="#">Test 2</a>
```

Comment: anchor tags inside anchor tags are illegal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: WTF! How did I not know this?!

Comment: plus why would you want an anchor inside an anchor?

Comment: I intended to give nested anchor absolute positioning with higher z-index so nested anchor could be clicked over parent anchor!

Comment: i'm absolutely sure, for any kind of problem that you was faced, its not a good solution, say about your problem to give you better solution than nested link!!