# why href not working when anchor is dynamically created inside another anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

Scenario 1 :

I have an anchor with `onclick="return false;"` and then I am adding another anchor inside it dynamically. The `href` is not working when the parent anchor has `onclick="return false;"` but it works fine when i remove that `onclick`.

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <a id="link1" onclick="return false;"></a>
    <script>
       var link = document.getElementById('link1')
       var newLink = document.createElement('a')
       newLink.setAttribute('href','https://wwww.google.com')
       newLink.innerHTML="google"
       //link.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newLink)
       link.appendChild(newLink)
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Scenario 2 :

I just have two anchors with parent anchor having `onclick` as `return false`. but in this case the inner anchor's `href` works fine.

```
<a onclick="return false;"><a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></a>
```

**So the problem is, when I am adding anchor dynamically inside another anchor with `onclick` as `return false` then the inner anchor's `href` is not working but it is working fine when they are statically created.**

**Can anybody please help me understand this behavior?**

Comment: Why you are doing this nonsense?

Comment: Nested anchor tags are illegal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: Check out event bubbling https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing , and as other commentators have pointed out, nested anchor tags are an illegal  behaviour. Is there any reason you can't just redirect to an empty fragment instead of using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesn't parse it nested as you expect, but JavaScript manages to get in nested.

Nested `a` elements are forbidden in HTML syntax. HTML specifications do not say why; they just emphasize the rule.

On the practical side, browsers effectively enforce this restriction in their parsing rules, so unlike in many other issues, violating the specs just won’t work. The parsers effectively treat an `<a>` start tag inside an open a element as implicitly terminating the open element before starting a new one.

So if you write `<a href=foo>foo <a href=bar>bar</a> zap</a>`, you won’t get nested elements. Browsers will parse it as `<a href=foo>foo</a>`   `<a href=bar>bar</a>` `zap`, i.e. as two consecutive links followed by some plain text.