# How do we break HTML semantics by using <div> in ReactJs (Jsx)

Tags: html, reactjs

ReactJs docs says:

> Sometimes we break HTML semantics when we add `<div>` elements to our
>   JSX to make our React code work, especially when working with lists
>   (`<ol>, <ul> and <dl>`) and the HTML `<table>`. In these cases we should
>   rather use React Fragments to group together multiple elements.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html

I would really like to understand that how do we break the HTML semantics by using `<div>` or the other elements mentioned above and how does the React Fragments is an improvement over that.

Also, I would like to understand that what are the problems that might arise by breaking of such semantics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are certain elements that should not be children of other elements in html. Anchor tags shouldn't be nested for instance. Or a `ul` can't have a `div` as a child. a `<React.Fragment>` element tells react that there is more than one element at the root level of the current component. React however needs to have a root level element. Most developers would throw a div around a component that renders list items (for instance), to get around the must have a parent issue. but that mucks up the DOM with extra `div`s and sometimes invalid child HTML elements

Comment: helpful links... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul look at `permitted content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you have a **<ul id="root">** element and you want to insert in it a couple of **<li>** tags. React element can only have single root node, so the first thing which come to mind is to wrap all **<li>** tags in a **<div>** e.g. the following:

```
  const element = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <li>Some list item</li>
         <li>Some other list item</li>
       </div>
     );
  };

  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Which will result in the following HTML:

```
<ul id="root">
    <div>
        <li>Some list item</li>
        <li>Some other list item</li>
    <div>
</ul>
```

Now we successfully broke the HTML semantics, it is not valid HTML to have a div directly inside a ul element. One way to avoid that is by using **React Fragments**:

```
  const element = () => {
     return (
       <Fragment>
         <li>Some list item</li>
         <li>Some other list item</li>
       </Fragment>
     );
  };

  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The Fragment doesn't insert extra HTML tag which won't broke the semantics. Here is the resulting HTML

```
<ul id="root">
    <li>Some list item</li>
    <li>Some other list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, one remark: "Now we successfully broke the HTML semantics" – perhaps you could emphasize here that it is not valid HTML to have a div directly inside a ul element

Comment: @Patrick Hund: I get the impression that "semantics" was the wrong word for the documentation to use to begin with... as you've pointed out, this is entirely a matter of valid markup, and the phrase "breaking semantics" itself doesn't make much sense.