# How to set href attribute of child in wrapped tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have 3 divs called `wrapper1`. Inside there is `wrapper 2`. Inside there is some text and a button. The question is: how can I get the href from the button, add an a tag around wrapper 2 and add the href to the a tag.

This is what I have so far, finding all `wrapper1`, add an a tag around `wrapper2`. But I don't get how I can read and write the href.

Final result should be

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <a href="http://www.ipsum.de">
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <p>content</p>
      <a href="http://www.ipsum.de">button</a>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.wrapper1 .wrapper2').wrap('<a class="lorem" href="???"a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="http://www.ipsum.de">button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jqksp4xn/

Comment: you can't wrap all that in an anchor as you will have a nested anchor which is invalid - instead perhaps use window.location onclick of wrapper 1 to redirect to the link href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal), using nested anchor tag is invalid in html.

Use [`.wrap( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) that allow you to modify wrapped tag content in callback function.

```js
$('.wrapper1 .wrapper2').wrap(function(){
  return '<a href="'+$(this).find('a').remove().attr('href')+'"></a>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <p>content</p>
    <a href="http://www.ipsum.de">button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```