# Bootstrap button & Post with specific category

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I don't know, what is missing in the codes. Title is visible, but url function has some error. Anyone please help.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-light btn-block text-left" href="<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
 <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?> rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?>"</a>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?></a>
```

I want to retrieve url correctly. Anyone please help.

Comment: I didn't get point for nesting anchor tags. Can you explain a bit what do you want to achieve? Your HTML is not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqbNSVPRSxHG_f_1VZ7ptpRBUGE8M1iw/view?usp=sharing

Please check this image, i want to make like this.

Comment: Still not clear, try with words.

Comment: If you check the codes, permalink is not visible or link is not opening. 
Conclusion is, i want to get posts from any specific category, in bootstrap button style.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, done.