# WordPress: Add link to specific page title

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to add a link to a specific page title in WordPress? So I've this link here:

```
<a id="info-button" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">info</i></a>
```

And this should be included here:

[image]

But when I try to save it WordPress has a problem with this. In the end this link looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - is the link supposed to link to the URL of a particular page, and if so, where should this link appear?

Comment: The title of a page is used in links to that page, from other parts of the site (eg. menus etc) and so trying to make that title a link doesn't make sense as you can't put an `<a>` tag within an `<a>` tag (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal) - What is your end goal?