# Using react-router Link with <a> tag

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

How can I use an  tag within  that we can use from react-router?

For example,

```
<Link to='/some-path'>
  <a href="https://....">Text </a>
</Link>
```

Since Link is effectively an anchor tag too, HTML throws an error saying that an  tag cannot be provided within another  tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `<Link>` ends up as `<a>` on the end? <Link> does not allow you to redirect to external sites etc

Comment: Same question, why do you need href if you are using Link with `to="some-route"` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I understand it might not be the best practice to do so. However my design is such that the Link is a big div with some text in it, while the inner a tag would be its supporting details that opens up separately in a new tab. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal