# 2 Overlapping Elements Won't Href To Their Sites Once Clicked

Tags: html, css, href, element, overlapping

Recently, I have been experimenting with elements specifically  tags. And when, I put  tag inside  tag and set their href="" to direct each to ones website they won't do it. They are overlapping elements and only the front  tag opens it's website, not the one inside.

[image]

I've tried setting the pointer-events to auto; for both of the elements but that would just make both highlightable and clickable which they already are lol. It's just that the frontal element is only clickable and not the one inside it.

```
<a href="https://google.com" style="display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;">
        <a href="yahoo.com" style="display: block;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: -50px;">
        </a>
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are nested anchor tags illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal)

Comment: I don't believe it to be illegal, but how could i go about opening 2 links at the same time with this method. Nested anchor links. @LeeTaylor

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? To open multiple pages see javascript's `window.open`. However, most users would find it irritating.

Comment: Well, I am trying to accomplish opening mutliple pages with this method. Not sure if it's impossible. I need to make opening of 2 pages with overlapped anchor elements work for a website. As there is an ad inside a <a> element on the page and, I need to make it so when users click on the ad. My link opens and the advertismnent.

Comment: See the link in my first comment. You cannot nest a tags. You can, however, open multiple pages at the same time.