# What is happening to jQuery.html. Why this code result is a mess?

Tags: javascript, jquery

who can explain me what's going on?

Take a look at this simple script: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xLs9s4s/)

```
var html;
html = '<a href="" class="_list-group-item">';
html += '<div class="media">';
html += '<div class="media-left padding-right-10">';
html += '<i class="icon wb-calendar bg-blue-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="media-body">';
html += '<p>hi, my name is Jo</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="media-right">';
html += '<small><a class="" data-notificationId="{{id}}" href="#">mark as read</a></small>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div></a>';

        console.log(html);
        $(".listContainer").html(html);
```

console.log shows the correct html code, the sequence (parent, child) is super simple:

a

div.media

div.left and close

div.body and close

div.right and close

close media

close a

But if you look at the result page with developers tools, the code is a mess. 
It writes the A tag and immediately close it.(??) 
Then div.media, followed by left and body inside another A tag (??) and finally, the div right.

Please tell me that you see this too, that it's not a joke of my browser.

Why this?

PS: I found this strange behavior while I was working with handlebars, trying to inject html code inside my list container.

PPS: Want to know another STRANGE thing? Everything is perfect if you delete the A tag from that string! ... Again, why?

Comment: It’s not correct to nest links inside other links.

Comment: Use click events instead.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666915/why-are-nested-anchor-tags-illegal

Comment: [alternative-to-nested-anchor-tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214363/alternative-to-nested-anchor-tags) might help you.

Comment: Wow! ... Thank you guys! :)